# specific config by environment in Scala

Tags: scala, configuration, environment-variables, config, development-environment

What is a good way to set up a project in Scala which uses different configuration depending on environments.

I need to specifically have different databases for **development**, **test** and **production** environment (similar to what is done in Rails)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Another strategy I'm using consists of using [*includes*](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#includes).
I usually store my DEV settings in the [default](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior) `application.conf` file then I create a new conf file for other environments and include the default one.

Let's say my DEV conf `application.conf` looks like this:

```
myapp {
    server-address = "localhost"
    server-port = 9000

    some-other-setting = "cool !"
}
```

Then for the PROD, I could have another file called `prod.conf`:

```
include "application"

# override default (DEV) settings
myapp {
    server-address = ${PROD_SERVER_HOSTNAME}
    server-port = ${PROD_SERVER_PORT}
}
```

Note that I override *only* the settings that change in the PROD environment (`some-other-setting` is thus the same as in DEV).

The config bootstrap code doesn't test anything

```
...
val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
...
```

To switch from the DEV to the PROD conf, simply pass a system property with the name of the config file to load:

```
java -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf ...
```

In DEV, no need to pass it since `application.conf` will be loaded by [default](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior).

So here we're using [Typesafe Config](https://lightbend.github.io/config)'s default loading mechanism to achieve this.

I've created a simple [project](https://github.com/ozeebee/test-scala-config) to demonstrate this technique. Feel free to clone and experiment.

Comment: For completeness, I believe the config bootstrap would be: val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
  def apply() = conf.getConfig("myapp")

Comment: @ozeebee for some reason this is not working. Notice that I added: `fork in run := true` and `java -Dconfig.resource=stg.conf` in build.sbt. File stg.conf is under resources but my config is still coming from application.conf. Notice too that when I use: `val conf = ConfigFactory.load("stg.conf")` then my configurations are loaded per stg.conf. Any idea?

Comment: @has981 no idea. I've setup a simple [project](https://github.com/ozeebee/test-scala-config) to demonstrate this technique. Feel free to clone and experiment.

Comment: @ozeebee your code is working fine on local but it`s not working when I deploy this code on flink with Docker and Kubernetes

Comment: @Kallz sorry but I don't know flink; Perhaps that this tool has its own configuration mechanism?

Answer (score 30):

Use typesafe Config. Create a Config object like this:

```
import com.typesafe.config._

object Config {
  val env = if (System.getenv("SCALA_ENV") == null) "development" else System.getenv("SCALA_ENV")

  val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
  def apply() = conf.getConfig(env)
}
```

Then create the `application.conf` file in `src/main/resources` folder:

```
development {
  your_app {
    databaseUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev_db"
    databaseUser = "xxxx"
    databasePassword = "xxxx"
  }
}
test {
  your_app {
    databaseUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db"
    databaseUser = "xxxxx"
    databasePassword = "xxxx"
  }
}
```

Now from anywhere in your application, you can access configuration:

Config().getString("your_app.databaseUrl")

If you have your environment set up (e.g. `export SCALA_ENV=test`) when you run your application, it will consider the right configuration section. The default is development

Comment: It took me a while to find this pattern which maintains the primacy of System Properties: ConfigFactory.defaultOverrides().withFallback(config2.getConfig(environment)).withFallback(config2); https://github.com/typesafehub/config/blob/master/examples/java/complex-app/src/main/java/ComplexApp.java

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't happy with how Daniel Cukiers solution did not allow defaults and overrides, so I changed it around to make full use of those.

The only configuration you have to do is set a ENVIRONMENT variable on the system (defaults to 'dev' if none is set)

(Java solution, compatible with Scala):

```
import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

public class MyCompanyConfig {
    public final static Config base = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("mycompany");
    public final static String environment = System.getenv("ENVIRONMENT") == null ? "dev" : System.getenv("ENVIRONMENT");

    /**
     * Returns a subtree of the base configuration with environment settings applied.
     *
     * @param setting The subtree to return config for.
     * @return A config with base in given setting, with environment modifications applied.
     */
    public static Config load(String setting) {

        Config config = base.getConfig(setting);

        if (config.hasPath(environment)) {
            return config.getConfig(environment).withFallback(config);
        }

        return config;
    }
}
```

This allows a single reference.conf in a library looking like this:

```
mycompany.module1 {
    setting1 : "adefaultvalue"
    url : "localhost"

    test {
        // will be used where ENVIRONMENT="test"
        url : "test.mycompany.com"
    }

    prod {
        // will be used where ENVIRONMENT="prod"
        setting1 : "changethedefault"
        url : "www.mycompany.com"
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Config conf = MyCompanyConfig.load("module1")
```